# Is there a way get name of a file without its extension through SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, plsql

I am writing a query that requires the name of a file from its directory location without its file path and file extension

Example: If a path exist `c:\temp\example.xls` I need the result of the query as just example .

I have referred to the site https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/filename.php , It shows a method of getting the filename with the extension. I was wondering is there another way just to get the filename.

This is the code I have used:

```
CREATE or REPLACE function get_filename
   (p_path IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN varchar2

IS
   v_file VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

   -- Parse string for UNIX system
   IF INSTR(p_path,'/') > 0 THEN
      v_file := SUBSTR(p_path,(INSTR(p_path,'/',-1,1)+1),length(p_path));

   -- Parse string for Windows system
   ELSIF INSTR(p_path,'\') > 0 THEN
      v_file := SUBSTR(p_path,(INSTR(p_path,'\',-1,1)+1),length(p_path));

   -- If no slashes were found, return the original string
   ELSE
      v_file := p_path;

   END IF;

   RETURN v_file;

END;
```

It creates a Function to get the filename from a location with its extension.

```
SELECT get_filename('c:\temp\example.xls')
FROM dual;
```

This SQL statement would return `example.xls`.Is there a way to just get `example` as the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd remove extension; search for the last dot (or, the first one if you look from right to left) and extract everything from the 1st character to the dot position. For example:

```
SQL> WITH test (v_file) AS
  2    (SELECT 'my example.xls' FROM DUAL)
  3  SELECT SUBSTR (v_file, 1, INSTR (v_file, '.', -1) - 1) result
  4    FROM test;

RESULT
----------
my example

SQL>
```

In your case, that would be

```
return SUBSTR (v_file, 1, INSTR (v_file, '.', -1) - 1)
```

Comment: You also need to chop off the path (using similar logic).

Comment: @Salman, the OP said that function returns "example.xls", so I removed only the extension. If there's something else to be removed, sure - that code should be adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR, twice:

```
WITH tests(filepath) AS (
    SELECT 'c:\path\to\example.xls' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c:\path\to\example' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'example.xls' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'example' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT filepath, REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(filepath, '[^\]+$'), '[^\.]+')
FROM tests
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need one call to REGEXP_SUBSTR. This example parses the whole path into it's parts.  For the OP's answer, you only need the 2nd call to REGEXP_SUBSTR.

EDIT: Updated, now handles filenames with multiple dots in them, and filenames that start with a dot.

```
WITH tbl(ID, fullpath) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'c:\path\to\example.xls' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'c:\path\to\example.1.2.xls' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
    SELECT 3, 'c:\path\to\example' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'example.xls' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'example.1.2.xls' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
    SELECT 6, 'example' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ID, fullpath, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(fullpath, '^(.*\\)?(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) path,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(fullpath, '^(.*\\)?(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) filename,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(fullpath, '^(.*\\)?(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)', 1, 1, null, 3) extension
FROM tbl
order by ID;


 ID FULLPATH                   PATH         FILENAME     EXTEN
--- -------------------------- ------------ ------------ -----
  1 c:\path\to\example.xls     c:\path\to\  example      .xls 
  2 c:\path\to\example.1.2.xls c:\path\to\  example.1.2  .xls 
  3 c:\path\to\example         c:\path\to\  example           
  4 example.xls                             example      .xls 
  5 example.1.2.xls                         example.1.2  .xls 
  6 example                                 example           
  7                                                           

7 rows selected.
```